# How to make emberjs app with a mobile look (like the one in jquery mobile)?

Tags: css, mobile, jquery-mobile, ember.js

I have a simple project of a web application for mobile using Emberjs. For the look and feel, I want something equivalent to JQuery Mobile. Is there a way to mix Emberjs and jquery mobile? If so, how?

I have looked at the Travis-ci mobile app and they seem to have only defined a specific css for the mobile version. What is strange is that they also have this file : [file](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/blob/master/app/assets/javascripts/mobile_app/views.js) that seems to be an attempt to integrate with JQMobile but they don't use it anywhere in the code.

I also have found this article [Using Ember.js with jQuery UI](http://www.lukemelia.com/blog/archives/2012/03/10/using-ember-js-with-jquery-ui/) but it's about JQuery UI. Can I use the same technique for JQuery Mobile?

Please share your own experience about having a mobile look and feel with Emberjs.

If you know any open source project on GitHub or wherever that uses Emberjs for mobile I will be thankful if you let me know the address.

What Technique do you recommend?

Note: I have make a first attempt to use the 'data-' html5 attributes of jquery mobile within a list generated by a controller but the elements of the view don't have change to a jquery mobile look and feel and I not sure why.

Sorry for my English, it is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Hey! I'm having similar concerns... Could you please share, what solution have you used finally? Any luck with using jquery-mobile together with ember?

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the [Ember.js wiki](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki/Modules) there are two projects concerning mobile:

- [ember-titanium](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-titanium) - Titanium Mobile wrapped in Ember (formerly SproutCore-Titanium)
- [ember-mk](https://github.com/ppcano/ember-mk) - Mobile Kit for ember.js

Maybe they are useful for you.

Comment: Thanks, I am not about learn at the same time also titanium... but perhaps when I will get use to emberjs

Answer (score 2):

@luissala created a proof of concept project using Ember with jQuery Mobile. It might get you on the right track:

https://github.com/LuisSala/emberjs-jqm

Comment: I just try to use this 'proof of concept' but I have issue with CollectionView as it seems deprecated and also 'itemViewClass' attribute seems to have disappear in the new version of emberjs. I will continue to dig.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Twitter Bootstrap: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

Comment: Yes it's true but bootstrap have more a desktop application look and feel. And I would like to have look and feel more like a apple basic ios application with basic linked list. Perhaps I will give it a try. Thanks for you reply it have give me new ideas.

Comment: Have you use it yourself to develop mobile app. Merci

Comment: I have just found http://ghempton.github.com/ember-layout-example/ that use bootstrap and  it look nice

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/fohr/blossom

Is in a very premature state, but it seems pretty promising. 
It's from the guys who started Sproutcore (I think!), so the syntax is very relevant to EmberJS

Comment: It look nice but seem to need a long learning curve to master the way to use it. And it's only a small project.