# Can I Use JQuery Mobile With EmberJS?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, ember.js

I want use JQuery mobile for the front-end of my mobile application, but I need a JavaScript MVC framework to do the back-end integration stuff and I'm looking at using EmberJS. Is there a guide for this kind of integration? Any pitfalls I should avoid? As a reference, I'm originally coming from a Sencha Touch 2.0 background.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hiya Hope following link helps you to right path for your questions: (Is there a guide for this kind of integration? )

Yep, you can **Basic proof of concept Ember.js with Jquery Mobile** => https://github.com/LuisSala/emberjs-jqm

little start up tutorial: http://www.andymatthews.net/read/2012/03/07/Getting-Started-With-EmberJS

Article: http://www.infoq.com/articles/emberjs

Ember Wiki has links to developer modules: https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/wiki

To start with and identify pitfalls:

(For proof of concept for your specific case you can also refer to the POC link I have shared above and glaze through the existing issues in stack overflow, Else I will go for head first and find out and fix the issues as go)

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/emberjs/new

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/emberjs

[How to make emberjs app with a mobile look (like the one in jquery mobile)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9747966/how-to-make-emberjs-app-with-a-mobile-look-like-the-one-in-jquery-mobile)

Hope this helps,

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I have just start to develop in my free time a application based on the proof of concept Ember.js with Jquery Mobile => https://github.com/LuisSala/emberjs-jqm

I have extract the class define in the previous proof of concept and just create a new repo https://github.com/tolbard/ember-moving.

This is very basic and only support the default header, content, footer and list.

Any help with this will be welcome