# How do I include jQuery Mobile in my Emberjs Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, ember.js

Today I encounter a puzzling issue and after several hours of searching I am not able to find what is the problem. I am trying to include jquery mobile into my rails application. I have tried both manually referencing the library files and also using [jquery_mobile_rails](https://github.com/tscolari/jquery-mobile-rails) gem. Both method works as far as inserting the library into my application, however as soon as I add jquery mobile, my app no longer loads. When refreshing the page, it will not load. There are three errors in console:

**1st:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object <Ember.ArrayResourceController:ember141> has no method '_resourceRequest'
Jimux.appsMetaController.Em.ArrayResourceController.create.findAll
newFunc
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function) jquery.js:566
jQuery.extend.globalEval jquery.js:567
jQuery.ajaxSetup.converters.text script jquery.js:8107
ajaxConvert jquery.js:7992
done jquery.js:7628
callback jquery.js:8367
send jquery.js:8373
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery.js:7835
(anonymous function) jquery.js:5858
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:613
jQuery.fn.extend.domManip jquery.js:5855
jQuery.fn.extend.append jquery.js:5628
jQuery.fn.extend.wrapAll jquery.js:5585
(anonymous function) jquery.js:5603
jQuery.extend.each jquery.js:613
jQuery.fn.jQuery.each jquery.js:243
jQuery.fn.extend.wrapInner jquery.js:5598
$.extend.initializePage jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js:9063
(anonymous function) jquery.mobile-1.2.0.js:9142
fire jquery.js:976
self.fireWith jquery.js:1084
jQuery.extend.ready jquery.js:408
DOMContentLoaded
```

**2nd:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'set' of undefined
Ember.Application.registerInjection.injection
(anonymous function)
(anonymous function)
visit
DAG.topsort
Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.runInjections
Ember.Application.Ember.Namespace.extend.initialize
(anonymous function)
fire
self.fireWith
jQuery.extend.ready
```

**3rd:**

```
GET http://localhost:3000/assets/images/ajax-loader.gif 404 (Not Found)
```

As soon as I remove `//= require jquery.mobile-1.2.0` from `application.js`, my app works as expected again -- without any of the above errors. I am just wondering what could be happening here. I guess there may be some namespace collision, but I am not sure if this is the case and how to identify and fix it.

Any help with debugging this issue will be appreciated. If you are using Embeejs+jQueryMobile in a rails project, I would love to know how you are including the two libraries into your rails application, and if/how you are dealing with any conflict.

I am using Ember 1.0pre1, and a slightly modified version of ember-rest.

Answer (score 3):

If I recall correctly, jQuery Mobile manipulates the DOM a fair bit. That would likely be problematic with Ember, as Ember expects to not have other libraries manipulating DOM elements that it is tracking views or bindings for.

Comment: oh No! are you saying what I think you are saying? Do you think there are any ways around this issue? It is kind of strange, because I havent even started using jqm and I get those errors. Thanks for quick response btw, Luke!

Comment: @Aras - I'm not sure. There are indications that it is possible. e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857247/can-i-use-jquery-mobile-with-emberjs

Comment: yes that post made me believe it was possible. Although it is a few months old and things have changed a lot since then. I basically dont even get to load my app as soon as I reference jquery mobile, so I havent tried creating any jqm elements yet. You are much more experienced, do you have any hints how I could debug this issue to understand a bit more, or eliminate some assumptions? I am rather puzzled!

Comment: @Aras I would try isolating it to a simple ember app with jqm loaded in a jsfiddle to see if you get the same error