# ember-1.0.0-rc.1 + jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css [HowTo required]

Tags: jquery-mobile, ember.js, handlebars.js

How can I include jquery.mobile-style in recent ember applications? A howto and a jsFiddle would be awesome.

In my case I would like to style a list of links ==> Buttons

```
{#each entry in controller}}
      <li>              
          <div>              
              {{view "App.EntryView" contentBinding="entry"}}

              {{#linkTo "entries.entry" line}}
                {{entry.name}}
              {{/linkTo}}
          </div>          
      </li>
      {{else}}
      <li>Loading...</li>
    {{/each}}
```

I found two examples in deprecated versions, that it's possible.

[Sample from LuisSala](https://github.com/LuisSala/emberjs-jqm/blob/master/index.html)

[Tomasz Borowski](https://coderwall.com/p/ylogzg)

And a quick [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857247/can-i-use-jquery-mobile-with-emberjs) hint I found here.

I tried LuisSalas example with the recent versions:

```
<script src="js/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/lib/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/lib/handlebars.1.0.0-rc.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="js/lib/ember-1.0.0-rc.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css" />
```

Unfortunately the page keeps white. Same result, with my own app, after including jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js

Help would be great! ^Thx~ in advance.